# Displaying items after selecting category from drop down in same div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list and after selecting category it should display items of the category in same div.

I have written a function on "onChange" and it works also. When I click on soups it shows the items of soups then when I click on starters it should only show starters, but it shows soups items and below that it displays starters.

I tried using innerHTML and even document.write functions, but using document.write it refreshes the page and displays only items, my drop down and other stuff from the page is vanished.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the function.

```
<body>
    <div style="margin:left:80px;">
        <select id='menu' style='height:40px;width:160px;' onChange="displayItems()">
             <option value='items' selected='selected' disabled>Select Items</option>           
      <script>

       var rasvanti_menu=["Soup","Pasta","Pizza","Sandwich","Snacks","Starters","Bread","Rice","Rice/Noodles","Gravies","Beverages","Extras"];

        var rasvanti_soup=["Coriander soup","Cream of Veg soup","Cream of tomato soup","Hot and sour soup","Manchow soup","Palak soup","Sweet corn soup","Veg Clear soup"];

        var rasvanti_starters=["Baby Corn Chilli","Baby Corn Finger","Finger Chips","Harabhara Kabab","Manchurian Dry","Mushroom Tikka","Pan Crispy","Paneer 65","Paneer Chilly Dry","Paneer Malai Kabab","Paneer Manchurian Dry"];

              for(var i=0;i<=rasvanti_menu.length;i++)
             {
                 document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>"+rasvanti_menu[i]+"</option>");
             }

             var id = document.createElement("table");


    function displayItems() {
        var selectedMenu = document.getElementById('menu');
        var selectedSoup = selectedMenu.options[selectedMenu.selectedIndex].text;

        if (selectedSoup == "Soup") {
            for (var s = 0; s < rasvanti_soup.length; s++) {
                id.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + rasvanti_soup[s] + "</td></tr>";
                document.getElementById("items_tray").appendChild(id);
            }

        } else if (selectedSoup == "Starters") {
            for (var l = 0; l < rasvanti_starters.length; l++) {
                id.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + rasvanti_starters[l] + "</td></tr>";
                document.getElementById("items_tray").appendChild(id);
            }
        }
    }
 </select>

             <table id="items_tray">
             </table>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for the problem?

Comment: Please include a sample of your code. It is impossible to accurately determine the problem and answer your question without seeing what you are working with.

Comment: I have posted my function where i display items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code appears to be the fact that you are using a variable called 'id' without defining it? If you post your complete code, people will be able to suggest better solutions.

Comment: @Deepika I see. When using document.createElement('table');, you are creating a table. But, you need to attach the table into the page (otherwise where does the table belong?). I would suggest changing it to this: var id = document.getElementById('items_tray'); because it looks like that is where you want the results to go. Otherwise, an example of using createElement properly is available here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this as the new data gets appended to the existing data in the items_tray.

So before appending the data in the items_tray, try removing the innerHTML of the items_tray, something like this -

```
if(selectedSoup=="Soup"){
      document.getElementById("items_tray").innerHTML = "";
      for(var s=0;s<rasvanti_soup.length;s++){
          id.innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+rasvanti_soup[s]+"</td></tr>";
          document.getElementById("items_tray").appendChild(id);
      }
}
```

same goes for the second "if".

Hope this will work.

Comment: I tried it Abhishek, doesn't work. :(  I have posted the whole code.